# 'QCombination' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with a query when executed it gives me error. But if run from the console django, I return the results correctly

In python shell (python manage.py shell)

```
>>> from api.models import User
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> User.objects.filter(Q(username__contains='lucas'))
[<User: @lucas>, <User: @lucasfuentes>, <User: @lucas_gasolero>]
```

In views.py

```
def search(req, keyword):
    users = User.objects.filter(
        Q(username__contains='lucas') | Q(name__contains='lucas')
    )
    [..]
```

ERROR: 'QCombination' object is not iterable

```
Traceback:
File "[..]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "[..]/api/views.py" in search
    84.    Q(username__contains='lucas') | Q(name__contains='lucas')

File "[..]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in filter
    155.    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "[..]lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
    669.    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "[..]lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
    687.    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "[..]lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
    1271.    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "[..]lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
    1066.    arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: TypeError at /v1/search/as/
Exception Value: 'QCombination' object is not iterable
```

Comment: In the shell it's not the same query. Have you tried in the shell `Q(username__contains='lucas') | Q(name__contains='lucas')`?

Comment: Is the same. In views.py `Q(username__contains='lucas') - ERROR 'Q' object is not iterable`. In shell `Q(username__contains='lucas') | Q(name__contains='lucas')` no error!! :(

Comment: @lucasmg, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes. Know the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Like @Nil said, but check the Q import in views.py. It may not be the `django.db.models.Q`!

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Turns out I was importing `elasticsearch_dsl.Q`

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answer, I'll try something. Make sure you import the right `User`. In [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#user-objects), it's imported like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

We can see that you use `from api.models import User` in your shell, but we don't see how you import `User` in your views. I know that it works in the shell with the "bad" import, but still, make sure you use the right import in both cases and tell us the result. If it still doesn't work, I have no idea, sorry!